# PyCharm Requires Login When Ran as Root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pycharm

The code inspection is not working properly on my Pop!_OS 21.04 x86_64, so I checked updates and realized that my PyCharm is actually out of date, but to update it I need to run PyCharm as root.

[image: update window]

But, when I go to where PyCharm is located and run `sudo ./pycharm.sh`, It's like it is a fresh install and wants me to login.

[image: login page]

I have come across this issue in other apps too, where if I run it as root, it uses a different directory for config etc.

How do I get around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are the only user of you computer the install pycharm to `~/opt` instead of `~/opt`. That way you will have automatic updates working.

Comment: I believe you made a mistake in your comment. `~/opt` instead of `~/opt` ?

Comment: No mistake, install pycharm in your home dir and don't worry about permissions. Alternative is to `chown` `/opt/pycharm*` before running update.